# How do I find a missing angle using a reciprocal trigonometric function?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I just attempted this as best as I could, but I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Here's the work:

$$\cot x =\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{\tan{x}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\frac{1}{\tan^{-1}\cdot\tan x} = \frac{1}{\tan^{-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\frac1x = \frac1{25.56505118}$$
$$x = 0.03911590057$$
Since I wasn't able to successfully search up anything relative to the matter, I'd appreciate if someone would tell me if this is correct. If not, then what are the correct steps that I'm supposed to take?

Comment: So you're looking for $x$, correct?  Are you looking for an analytic solution, or an approximation to some number of decimals?

Comment: @John Yes, I am looking for x, the degrees of the angle.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment when you responded.  I mean, $x = \arctan 2$ is a solution, but I guess you need something else?  Like an approximation, or possibly an exact solution in some closed form?

Comment: @John An approximation is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps, 
\[ \cot x =\frac{1}{2} \]
\[ \frac{1}{\tan x} =\frac{1}{2} \]
\[ \tan x =2 \]
\[ \arctan(\tan x)=\arctan 2 \]
\[ x =\arctan 2=1.1071487\ \mbox{rad}= 63.43^{\circ} \]

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do; thank you!

Comment: @user3758041, no problem. Keep practicing and eventually it'll be easy to you.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to edit your question since there are places I cannot determine your intent. But you can proceed this way:
$$\cot x = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{{\tan x}} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\tan x = 2$$
Can you continue from there?